# Recommendation for getting into a different field in Computer Science as first year CS master

Tags: research-process, masters, computer-science, supervision, research-topic

I am currently co-supervised by 2 profs and my Master's thesis would be on the intersection of both their work: along the lines of compiler, programming languages and machine learning.

However, I'm more interested in a related by slightly different area that none of them are currently focusing on (causality in ML). I have found another prof in this area and I am interested in applying for research intern. However, I only have 2 projects from undergrad that are related, but no publication/serious long research experience in that field.

I'm looking for recommendations on things I can do to demonstrate to this prof that "I have some knowledge in this field and I am willing to put in the effort" I hope there's a solution other than "just write a paper myself and go through the months of review".

A bit more context: This prof is young and have very little student, they are also in the same city as me, although a different university. Not sure if approach someone like this would be easier compared to more established profs.

Comment: Depends on the people. Honestly, when I started my PhD I had absolutely no background on the topic I did, other than "general engineering and programming skills".